# Using SDWebImage in my TableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode6, sdwebimage

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to use SDWebImage in my project for the first time and at the beginning I though that this is going to be easy but it's not. That's why I'm asking for your help because it's not working as they say in they website and I'm lost with that.

First of all, I need SDWebImage because I need to load asynchronously my images from a TableViewController.

That's my UITableView inside my TableViewController:

```
    #import "SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h"

    ...

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"carTableCell";

        CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                                  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[CarTableViewCell alloc]
                    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.makeLabel.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"];
        cell.likes.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"likes"];
        cell.comments.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"comments"];
        cell.username.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"username"];
        cell.refuser.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"user_ref"];

        cell.modelLabel.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"user"];

        NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imagen"]];
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        UIImage * carPhoto = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        cell.carImage.image = carPhoto;

        NSURL * imageURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image"]];
        NSData * imageData2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL2];
        UIImage * carPhoto2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData2];

        cell.profileImage.image = carPhoto2;

// LINES INCLUDED FROM THE SDWebImage website steps:
// Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
        [cell.carImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
// END        
        return cell;
    }
```

I have included all the files from the SDWebImage downloaded from the GitHUB, but when I write the new lines, I get the following error:

```
CarTableViewController.m:82:21: No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:'
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I have a problem with importing the category because I can't use "<>" because I get an error.

Comment: Try using Cocoapods to install SDWebImage. Cocoapods is a nice way to managing and importing libraries used in an Xcode project.